# Aggregating on a table with 5Million+ rows

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Table Name: items
**Table Columns**

```
id : Primary Key -> VARCHAR
platform: non unique index -> VARCHAR
name -> VARCHAR
full_name -> VARCHAR
additional_details -> JSONB
```

*I am using PostgreSQL - AWS RDS with 16GB RAM*

Is there any better hosting platform ? Because when I run PostgreSQL on my local the queries are 2 times faster but I don't want the overhead of managing the servers once it foes to production.

There is only this table where I am trying to run the aggregation.
This is a part of a web application running using fastapi.
When sending concurrently 200 requests at a time the database just hangs and the cpu goes to 100%
The response time for querying the first time is less than 1 second but it increases to around 20 seconds as the number of concurrent requests is increased to 200 even if I keep the query same (that means that the result of the query is not getting cached in PostGRESQL).

The platform column is indexed (btree).
Basically the query i am running is "select platform, count(*) from items group by platform;"

I am using SqlAlchemy 2 as ORM to interact with the database.

Is VARCHAR the problem here ? Earlier I was using ElasticSearch but I am looking at PostgreSQL as it handles the writes better.

Please suggest as I am finding the count queries to be a deal breaker when testing with PostgreSQL

Thanks

Tried indexing the column first but nothing happens.

### The explain analyze gives this result:
QUERY PLAN

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.46..286682.22 rows=4 width=14) (actual time=1945.237..5100.088 rows=6 loops=1)
   Group Key: platorm
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.46..286682.14 rows=8 width=14) (actual time=775.604..5100.048 rows=14 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..285681.19 rows=4 width=14) (actual time=754.438..4028.175 rows=5 loops=3)
               Group Key: platorm
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_platform on assets  (cost=0.43..270172.42 rows=3101747 width=6) (actual time=1.617..3681.938 rows=2454018 loops=3)
                     Heap Fetches: 1027997
 Planning Time: 35.279 ms
 Execution Time: 5106.731 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: What is the point of running the same query 200 times concurrently?  This sounds less like testing, and more like vandalism.

Comment: @jjanes Yes it for testing that the web app can handle 200 aggregation query requests at a time.

Comment: "*When sending concurrently 200 requests at a time the database just hangs and the cpu goes to 100%*" - well then your hardware doesn't match your performance requirements. You will need to add more CPUs (and probably faster disks as well)

Comment: "Planning Time: 35.279 ms", this is already very slow. For such a simple query, the planning time should be sub millisecond, about a hundred times or more faster than the current situation. Do you have any details about this (virtual) platform?

Comment: @FrankHeikens
 Planning Time: 2.586 ms
 Execution Time: 748.790 ms
This is what I am getting now. I think I took the earlier one when the other APIs were working.
I have 16 GB of RAM in my instance. It is a AWS RDS Serverless V2 instance.
There are more than 5Million rows in this table.
How much CPU do you think is required here for this to work in multiple concurrent processes? In production we will keep the size of the tables smaller than this by splitting data in multiple tables based on some key but it will go upto 1 Million for one or two tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you have any recommendations based on the fact that there will be tables with around 1 Million rows ? How much ram should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't cache query results. Each concurrent query runs independently and each may return different results depending on the transactions that have committed prior to the start of each query. Remember, these are concurrent, not simultaneous, queries. The increase in average wall clock time required for the queries is most likely due to the increased resource demand. Given that changing from a single query to 200 concurrent queries changed the result time from 1 to 20 seconds, I would suspect that you might be able to run 10 concurrent queries in about the same time as running the single query. How many CPUs are available in your environment?

Elasticsearch, and other tools, perform query result caching. The use of caching can greatly improve performance when multiple identical queries are requested in a short time span; however, this comes at the cost of possibly stale results if there aren't mechanisms in place to invalidate the cache when the underlying data changes.

The data type isn't the problem here. The problem is a design that requires more resources than available to achieve the desired performance level.

Comment: Right now we have only 1 cpu with 16GB Ram. Right now I am using a single query for all the aggregations but in production environment the queries running will be different and there will be around 20 aggregation queries running concurrently, though the table size will not be 5Million, it will be around 100,000 or less than that.

Comment: Is there a way I can write a framework on top of postgresql to cache the aggregation results before the real queries hit it ? or may be do it while performing CRUD on the database ? Or is there a way to make my aggregation more efficient that it does not end up taking the full cpu ?

Thanks

Comment: Without the actual query and the table and index details, there's not much more we can offer. From your description of the query and the explain plan, it looks like the query is already being processed efficiently.

Comment: You might consider using a materialized view. Unfortunately, PostgreSQL doesn't support incremental updates to materlized views, so the view would have to be refreshed in full each time the underlying data changes. Meaningful answers to your questions require more details about the overall system, use cases, and performance requirements.

Comment: Our use case is basically for reporting. We were using elastic earlier but the problem is that the write is extremely slow as the index size increases and we need to write a lot of data everyday. We started experimenting with Postgres and found that writes are very fast and we want to use it. But it's inability to query aggregation data is some thing that we cant take.

Comment: We are running a multi tenant application.For each tenant we are running 100 aggregation queries per company for a tenant which they can schedule once a day and we have like 5000 such tenants having 50 companies on average. 
Please also suggest a better managed hosting platform for postgresql. Currently we are using AWS RDS Aurora DB with 32 GB RAM.

Comment: We will upgrade the cpu once we go to production, but we need to verify the aggregation speed first which is looking to be very slow for concurrent executes. How does postgresql load data in memory? is it loading all the rows at once and running out of memory ?

Thanks

Comment: Without significantly more details, it's not possible to adequately respond to many of these questions. The discussion has also strayed from addressing a single question into broader solution design. I suggest that the approach is fundamentally flawed. Explore options that facilitate incremental refresh of the aggregates. A publisher/subscriber architecure could be a practical basis for a solution. Take a look at NOTIFY/LISTEN in the PostgreSQL documentation.